# Safest way to store environment variable value in a file

Tags: bash, scripting

I am using `bash` and most interested in an answer for `bash`, but you can answer about how to do it in other shells if you want.

I have an environment variable, `KEY`, and I want to store the value of that environment variable in a a file. Currently I am doing

```
echo "${KEY}" > ./key.pem
```

In practice this seems to be OK, but in theory this breaks when `KEY=-n`.

```
$ export KEY=-n
$ echo BEGIN "${KEY}" END
BEGIN -n END
$ echo "${KEY}" END
END$
```

So, is there a better way to store the value of a single environment variable in a file? (Note that `export` and `declare` will include the name of the variable in their outputs, which is no good for me.)

Comment: What will use the file? Will it be used to set the value again in a shell script, or by some other tool?

Comment: @drewbenn `echo -- "$KEY"` would not help. It would output `-- -n`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, I'm a bit disappointed that all my shells _consistently_ output `-- -n`

Comment: This is one of the reasons why [`printf` is always better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222) when you don't have complete control over what input you want to print.

Comment: @ilkkachu Hmm... Usually, consistency is considered a _good_ thing ;-)

Comment: it's not that hard to use a switch either.  -n

Comment: @ilkkachu, the `rc` clone for Unix and its es/akanga derivatives support `echo --`. Early versions of `zsh` did as well, but the end-of-option delimiter later changed to `-` for consistency with Bourne/Korn shell and builtins I suppose.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, and `fish` (2.7.1) too. I'm not sure if I should say I'm happy now...

Comment: @ilkkachu, the problem is that POSIX **forbids** `echo` from supporting an end-of-option marker. I did ask that zsh's `-` be allowed but it was rejected. See http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=1222 (linked from the [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) Q&A)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If it's storing for the sake of reading it in later (in a `bash` script), just use `declare -p KEY` and then source the file to read it in again. If you just want to store the value, use `printf '%s\n' "$KEY"` as you would do when you output any variable data.

So,

```sh
printf '%s\n' "$KEY" >key.pem
```

or

```
printf 'BEGIN %s END\n' "$KEY" >key.pem
```

or whatever you need to output.

Your issue occurs since `-n` is a valid option to `echo` in `bash`. The strings `-e` and `-E` (and combinations like `-neEne`) would also cause issues in `bash`, for the same reason. Depending on how `bash` is built or the environment or options, backslash characters in arguments may also be a problem.

These issues and more are outlined in the following Q/A:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Answer (score 8):

Many systems have a `printenv` command that outputs the contents of the given environment variable followed by one newline character to standard output (`printenv` appeared in 3BSD in the late 70s):

```
printenv 'My Env Var' > file
```

Would store the content of the `My Env Var` variable followed by NL into `file` in all shells on those systems.

For environment variables that are mapped to shell variables (includes at least those whose name starts with an ASCII letter or underscore and are followed by 0 or more ASCII letters, digits or underscore, and are not otherwise special variables set by the shell), in Bourne-like shells (also works in `fish`), you can do the same with:

```
printf '%s\n' "$ENVVAR" > file
```

(though if the variable is unset, that will still store an empty line into `file`)

In `rc`-like shells (where all shell variables are mapped to environment variables):

```
printf '%s\n' $ENVVAR > file
printf '%s\n' $'My Env Var' > file
```

(same caveat as above)

In `csh`-like shells:

```
printf '%s\n' $ENVVAR:q > file
```

(if the variable is not set, it will fail and not overwrite `file`)

Some implementations/versions of `ksh` don't have `printf` builtin. In those, you could also do:

```
print -r -- "$ENVVAR" > file
```